# Error al restar dos arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x, array, pandas, numpy

Hola tengo un problema a la hora de restar dos vectores columna:

Tengo un vector columna llamado outputs de tamaño 453x1 con puros "0 y 1", otro generado mediante números aleatorios y multiplicación de matrices (pero al final del mismo tamaño, 453x1), pero a la hora de restarlos obtengo una matriz de tamaño 453×2 con todos los elementos "NaN". No sé a que se debe esto, en un principio creí que había algún símbolo en el vector "outputs" que podía provocar el problema, pero ya revisé parece que no, llevo días tratando de ver que está fallando.

```
def l2_cost(outputs, hidden_2,deriv=True):
if deriv==True:
    return (outputs-hidden_2)
return np.mean(outputs-hidden_2)**2
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Faltó agregar como están definidos ambos vectores porque si te fijas los dos tienen índices distintos. Prueba con `outputs["1.0"]-hidden_2["0"]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que `hidden_2` y `outputs` son dos Dataframes. Al restar dos DataFrames, la operación se realiza sobre las columnas en común y en tu caso no hay columnas en común, una se llama `0` y la otra `1.0`.

Tienes varias opciones:

```
import pandas as pd


hidden_2 = pd.DataFrame({"0": (0.885124, 0.845425, 0.920863)})
outputs = pd.DataFrame({"1.0": (0.0, 1.0, 1.0)})


def l2_cost(outputs, hidden_2, deriv=True):
    if deriv==True:
        return (outputs-hidden_2)
    return np.mean(outputs-hidden_2)**2
```

### Pasar a la función las columnas (`pd.Series)`

> ```
> >>> l2_cost(outputs["1.0"], hidden_2["0"])
>
> 0   -0.885124
> 1    0.154575
> 2    0.079137
> dtype: float64
> ```

El resultado es una Serie

### Pasar los DataFrames, pero renombrando una de las dos columnas

> ```
> >>> outputs.columns = ["0"]
> >>> l2_cost(outputs, hidden_2)
>
>           0
> 0 -0.885124
> 1  0.154575
> 2  0.079137
> ```

El resultado es un DataFrame.

### Pasar dos arrays de NumPy directamente

```
>>> l2_cost(outputs.to_numpy(), hidden_2.to_numpy())

array([[-0.885124],
       [ 0.154575],
       [ 0.079137]])
```

El resultado será un `numpy.narray`

Comment: Muchas gracias por las propuestas!